# Using different authentication for different operations in ModelViewSet in Django REST framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have the following ModelViewSet

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows users to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, MyUserPermissions)
```

I want the `create method (POST on /users/)` to not ask for any authentication. How can I override the authentication_classes in this case? I'm talking about `ModelViewSet` not generic API views.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I want the create method (POST on /users/) to not ask for any authentication.

Actually that's not quite what you want.  You want `POST` on users to not require any *permissions*, which will have the effect that either authenticated or unauthenticated requests will succeed.

I'd suggest overriding your permission classes so that they always allow `POST` requests.  Follow the [custom permissions documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions#examples) for more info on that.

Essentially you'll have something like:

```
class IsAuthenticatedOrCreate(permissions.IsAuthenticated):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            return True
        return super(IsAuthenticatedOrCreate, self).has_permission(request, view)
```

And probably something similar for your other permission class too.