# Different authentications and permissions in ModelViewSet - Django REST framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

This question is similar to this one: [Using different authentication for different operations in ModelViewSet in Django REST framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22196697/using-different-authentication-for-different-operations-in-modelviewset-in-djang), but it didn't work for me.

I've got the following viewset:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    queryset = UserProfile.objects.none()
    permission_classes = [SpecialPermission]
```

SpecialPermission looks like this:

```
class SpecialPermission(IsAuthenticated):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            return True
        return super().has_permission(request, view)
```

REST framework settings:

```
"DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": ["backend.api.authentication.ExpiringTokenAuthentication"],
"DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES": ["rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated"],
```

I want to everybody to be able to post to UserViewSet but every other method should require Authentication. However, with the code above I get an Unauthorized Response on post.

What do I need to change?

Comment: did you try `return super(SpecialPermission,self).has_permission(request, view)` ?

Comment: It doesn't even call has_permission it returns unauthorized before it gets to the permissions

Comment: why do you use `queryset = UserProfile.objects.none()`

Comment: it seems like you are using model Permission and in the doc here [https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#djangomodelpermissions](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#djangomodelpermissions) might help

Comment: I use queryset.none() for security reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it can be done, this requirement imo does not justify this ifology as auth/user related stuff should be clean and secure.

Instead extract POST method from this viewset to its own class.

```
class UserViewSet(mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                   mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                   mixins.DestroyModelMixin,
                   mixins.ListModelMixin,
                   GenericViewSet):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    queryset = UserProfile.objects.none()
    permission_classes = [SpecialPermission]
```

```
class CreateUserView(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    queryset = UserProfile.objects.none()
    authentication_classes = []
```

---

if you really want to disable authentication in this viewset I'd rather recommend this

```
    def get_authenticators(self):
        if self.action == 'create':
            return []
        return super().get_authenticators()
```

That's more explicit than your solution.

Comment: I want every api point to appear in my drf router and have a clean url structure. I don't want an extra api endpoint just fo create. Although I gotta admit that from a code perspective it is clean.

Comment: I think you can plug it into the same URL without a problem though. Anyway, I added another solution.

Comment: No, DRF does not allow to plug multiple views (not overlapped METHODs) into the same path (URL).

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out: Making perform_authentication lazy solved my problem. Now I can post but authentication still runs on all other methods where it is needed.

```
 def perform_authentication(self, request):
        """
        Perform authentication on the incoming request.

        Note that if you override this and simply 'pass', then authentication
        will instead be performed lazily, the first time either
        `request.user` or `request.auth` is accessed.
        """
        pass
```